# PHP: count down clock

Tags: php, time, clock

I want to create a timer in PHP that will count down every second. I have some code that works but there's a problem:

```
for($countdown=20; $countdown >= 0; $countdown--)
{   
    echo "$countdown\n"; //print out the time left
    sleep(1);            //wait one second

    if ($countdown == 0)
    {
        displayscore();
        endgame();
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that when the script is sleeping, it can't do anything else, such as track the player in the game script I'm writing.
How would I go about making a countdown timer in php without using sleep? Perhaps unixtime or clocks units?

Any help would be appreciated

I will elaborate: When someone hits the "finish" in a game I am writing, it calls several functions, and this countdown is one of the functions. Problem is, it can't execute these other functions while it is sleeping.

Comment: Additional the timer will probably not be very accurate, because `displayscore()` and `endgame()` consumes time too. Ever considered using javascript?

Comment: huh? track the player in a running script? I cannot imagine what you're trying to do.

Comment: Those are only displayed when the countdown is 0 so it's only consuming time when it gets to time 0, no? If not, it doesn't matter since this doesn't need to be very accurate

Comment: @yi_H not really, but that's not the point, I just want to create a timer that doesn't freeze the whole script

Comment: why don't tell us what you're trying to do? Trust me, what you described doesn't make much sense

Comment: This is a cli/desktop php app right? Because this makes no sense for if you are using a browser.

Comment: nope not a browser script. And I will elaborate: When someone hits the "finish" in a game I am writing, it calls several functions, and this countdown is one of the functions. Problem is, it can't execute these other functions while it is sleeping.

Comment: It can't execute other functions while it's in the loop either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of actually counting 20 seconds, maybe you can just store the time that the process starts and then compare it to the current time, to tell when 20 seconds has passed.